# How to create CX509PublicKey object from a public key byte array

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, key, rsa

I have created a RSA key pair, fetched the public key, cahnged it to byte array and sent it to another API for further flow. There i need a  CX509PublicKey to be generated from the received byte array. How to do that?

Following is the code

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        var pk = RSA.ExportRSAPublicKey();
        return pk;
```

AND

```
CX509PublicKey cpk = new CX509PublicKey(pk);

        var objPkcs10 = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();
        objPkcs10.InitializeFromPublicKeyTemplate(
            X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser,
            pk, objPolicyServer,
            template);
```

The above code doesn't work! need to convert that pk to CX509PublicKey object. Please Help!

Comment: You probably need to convert your PKCS#1 formatted public key to a SubjectPublicKeyInfo. I don't have much time to figure out how to do this, but this should give you some search hints.

Answer (score 1):

The [PublicKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certenroll/nf-certenroll-ix509publickey-initializefromencodedpublickeyinfo) takes e.g. base64 as input.